# Establish identitiy $(\cos\theta - \sin\theta)^2 + (\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^2 = 2$

Tags: trigonometry

Hey guys this is the question:

$$(\cos\theta - \sin\theta)^2 +  (\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^2 = 2$$

I did this before but I forgot how I did it.. I tried to do this but don't know how to continue.. btw I can only use identity formulas, so please don't answer with other formulas I don't know about...

$$\cos^2\theta  - 2\cos\theta\sin\theta + \sin^2\theta + 1 = 2$$

$$1 - 2\cos\theta\sin\theta = 2$$

then idk.. please help!

Comment: For a coder like you, it shouldn't be too hard to put your question in the appropriate format...

Comment: Im Mainly a programmer @imranfat i dont know how to use the MathJax ... sorry..

Comment: Mathjax is much easier than programming....

Comment: @imranfat yes.. but i dont want to learn Mathjax.. ill rather get more give time to more C++ Programming or school stuff...

Comment: Not wanting to learn???

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics using MathJax.  Not writing your questions in MathJax is an imposition on the rest of us since it makes your questions difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set: $a=\cos \theta$, $b=\sin\theta$. Then:

$(a-b)^2 + (a+b)^2
= a^2 -2ab + b^2 + a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = 2a^2 + 2b^2 = 2(a^2 + b^2)=2(\sin\theta^2 + \cos\theta^2)=2.$

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab+b^2, (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab+b^2$, and $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$. Use the above formulas with $a = \sin \theta,  b = \cos \theta $.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\left(\cos\theta - \sin\theta\right)^2 + \left(\cos\theta + \sin\theta\right)^2&=\cos^2\theta\cancel{-2\sin\theta\cos\theta}+\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cancel{+2\sin\theta\cos\theta}+\sin^2\theta\\
&=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\\
&=1+1\\
&=2
\end{align}
$$